# Magento 2.3.6 - Admin session times out to early

Tags: php, admin, magento2.3.6

I have some issues where my Magento admin session times out way before what it should.

I found this GitHub link where they say you need to add this code to php.ini:
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime

However I do not have access to that, and some say you can paste it in the .httaccess file, but I'm not 100% sure where I can paste this? Does anyone know where I can do this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked on below configuration path in admin??

> Store-> Configuration ->Advance -> Admin -> Security ->  Admin Session
> Lifetime (seconds)

set "31536000" in above confiuguration

hope this helps you :)

Comment: I have already done this, and it still logs me out after 900 seconds

Comment: okay then check phpinfo() and upgrade value for "session.gc_maxlifetime"

Comment: Where do i find PHPInfo?

Comment: in magento root create test.php file and add <?php phpinfo(); ?> and run this file in browser eg. https://example.com/test.php